# Get sharepoint api access token using userName and password in Dot Net Core (all available solutions show for Dot net framework)

Tags: authentication, .net-core, sharepoint, access-token

I am trying to get sharepoint access token for sharepoint api by using userName and password.

I tried using "SharePointOnlineCredentials" method from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client but this is not supported by .net core.

Is there any package supported in .net core where I can get the access_token using userName and password?

ClientId and ClientSecret is not an option as I do not have this information.

Please help!